# Do I need to recreate DataInputStream or DataOutputStream after each input/output

Tags: java, sockets, multiplayer

Hello so I was just wondering.
I am creating multiplayer for my game and if I want to send something
 should I use:

```
dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
dos.writeUTF(username);

dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
dos.writeUTF("test");

dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
String loginResponse = dis.readUTF();
```

or should I use:

```
dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
dos.writeUTF(username);
dos.writeUTF("test");

dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
String loginResponse = dis.readUTF();
```

Comment: What makes you think you'd need a new stream for every operation?

Comment: A tutorial I watched on Youtube, but I think that is nonsense, just not sure

Answer (score 1):

You should create one IOStream and do with it what you need to do with it, without creating a new one every time.

If you would create a new one everytime, theoretically you'd just be filling up memory unnecessarily.

Comment: Not only that, but because of the BufferedIn/OutputStream he would miss data as well (sending and receiving).